# Dynamic GIT repositories from Jenkins job

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to analyse if this is possible with Jenkins.

I want to create/setup a new repository in GIT based on a Jenkins job. Basically if I decide to start a new project, I will trigger a build job called "Setup-new-project". Which should eventually do the following:

1. Create a new repository in Git
2. Generate a skeleton project from maven artefact
3. Commit this skeleton project to the newly created Git repo.

Further I can share this repository to the developers and start building things on top of it.

I have been playing around Jenkins and Git for quite a while, then I realised that bringing up a new project is consuming a lot of time. :)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: You can just create a script and re run whenever you want to create a new project.

Comment: This may be a "write-my-code" question, @pratZ.  Could you provide the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a script for it with:

- git repository init;
- mvn archetype plugin call (if I understand you correctly; anyway, you could call any maven goal);
- git adding all;
- git commit.

Then you should create simple job in Jenkins with one script step (for example, sh script, if you are using linux). Also, it is a good idea to make a parametrized build to be able to provide repo name/ initial dir and so on.